# I use HTTP Basic Auth in my Django REST application. How can I add authentication to my WebSockets through Django Channels?

Tags: python, django, authentication, websocket, django-rest-framework

My back end application currently uses HTTP Basic Auth for authentication. I need to add a WebSocket Channel with the [Django Channel](http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) official plug-in.

How would I go about doing this?